# Powershell output to a text file

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script that pulls all of the date and time information from our servers. The script gets the servers from a text file. I am having is getting the output of a script to be written to a text file.

I tried using a pipe with Out-File like so:

```
$servers = gc "C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestList.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers){
$dt = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computer $server
$dt_str = $dt.converttodatetime($dt.localdatetime)
write-host "$($server) current local time is $($dt_str)" | Out-File 
"C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestListOutput.txt"
```

Then I tried the simple carrot output like so:

```
$servers = gc "C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestList.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers){
$dt = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computer $server
$dt_str = $dt.converttodatetime($dt.localdatetime)
write-host "$($server) current local time is $($dt_str)" > 
C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestListOutput.txt
```

And that did not work either. So any help or advice would be excellent.

TL;DR Trying to get the powershell output into a text file or some other more usable file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `write-host` - use `write-output`

`write-host` will only output your string to the console, the data will not be passed along the pipleline.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `write-output` you can just

```
"text" | Out-File ...
```

> into a text file or some other more usable file format

CSV is a more usable format. The format you're writing is something you will have to process again to get the data back out of the text. CSV you can just `Import-Csv` to get it back. Or open in Excel, etc.

```
gc "C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestList.txt" | ForEach {

    $dt = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -Computer $_

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ServerName' = $_
        'DateTime' = $dt.converttodatetime($dt.localdatetime)
    }

} | Export-Csv C:\Users\Public\Shell_NTP\TestListOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```